# sum of 1, 2, 3... Two loop

Tags: java

I have a data from loop two.

```
Tsum2 :  [ 19  12  17  10  6   0   10...  ]   
Isum2 :  [ 98  33  26  11  15  10  32...  ]
```

and I want sum of value `Tsum2` and `Isum2`

```
sum = [ (19-98)+(12-33)+(17-26)+ ... +(10-32)... ]
```

What do I do?

This code Example

```
for (int d1 = 0; d1 < 360; d1++) {
    Tsum10 = Tsum10 + (int) degreeT[d1];                
    Tcount10++;
    if (Tcount10 == 10) {
        Tsum2 = (Tsum10 + (int) degreeT[d1]);                
        Tcount10 = 0;
        Tsum10 = 0;          
    } 
} 

for (int d2 = 0; d2 < 360; d2++) {
    Isum10 = Isum10 + (int)degreeI[d2];                  
    Icount10++;
    if (Icount10 == 10) {
        Isum2 = (Isum10 + (int)degreeI[d2]);
        Icount10 = 0;
        Isum10 = 0;         
    } 
}
```

Result from this code.

loop d1:

```
19 12 17 10 6 0 10 21 28 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 31 7 13 9 16 8 8 13 16
```

loop d2:

```
98 33 26 11 15 10 32 44 87 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 112 50 14 25 32 16 32 39 97
```

Thank.

Comment: If I understand you are having two arrays:
Tsum2 : [ 19 12 17 ] and
Isum2 : [ 98 33 26 ] of same length then you want the sum = -109 ???

Comment: As a sidenote, you should stick to the java naming conventions for the naming of variables (starting in lowercase) otherwise it could confuse, since words starting with uppercase normally specify a class.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear. I don't understand why you set to 0 every value in multiple position of 11.
This is the solution for what i understand.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Tsum2.length; i++) {
    total += Tsum2[i] - Isum2[i]
}
```

Comment: This will work if `Tsum2` and `Isum2` have same number of elements. What if `Isum2[]` has [less elements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) than `Tsum1`.

Comment: @sam: Then OP needs to specifiy what should happen, since that breaks the specifications in the question.

Comment: I wrote this code because i saw that JJR KTS loop from 0 to 359 for each array. If they have different length he can check the smaller and iterate since its length then simply add (or subtract) the others. Sorry for my bad english xD

Answer (score 0):

Since you are subtracting items from 2 arrays that have the same index could you not use a for loop and simply keep a running total.

```
int sum=0;
for (int x = 0; x < Tsum1.length; x++) {
    sum= sum+ (Tsum2[x] - Isum2[x]);
}
```

Comment: You can use sum += instead of sum = sum + ;)

Comment: Yeah I just figured it would be easier to comprehend this way for the person asking the question but thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This solution should is working no matter if the arrays have the equals size or not and prevent an `ArrayOutOfBoundException`.

```
int[] tsum2 = { 19, 12, 17, 10, 6, 0, 10};
int[] isum2 = { 98, 33, 26, 11, 15, 10, 32};
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tsum2.length || i < isum2.length; i++) {
    int val1 = i < tsum2.length ?  tsum2[i] : 0;
    int val2 = i < isum2.length ?  isum2[i] : 0; 
    total += val1 - val2;
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to hold the sum of your arrays.

If you want to get the sum of two arrays you do it like:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < tsum2.length; i++)
{
    sum = sum + (array1[i] - array2[i]);
}
```

Also, all of your variables should be lowercase since they are not Classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out man:

```
const int n = 6;
int[] a = { 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 };
int[] b = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int d =0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
 {
    d += a[i] - b[i];
 }
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile. Mind that this is _not_ a C# question (looks like C# code).

Comment: Yeah it's c# .!! wats der in that he would atleast get an idea how to do na..:)